# Ruby Logical String comparison (eg. "a" > "b")

Tags: ruby, string, string-comparison, boolean-logic

Hy,

I am trying to understand how Ruby handles strings when comes to logical comparison.

I tried:

```
"a" > "b" #--> false
"ab" > "b" #--> false
"z" > "az" #--> true
# i even tried
"z" > "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" #--> true
```

Is like Ruby gives weight to characters from a(the weakest) to z(the strongest) and it doesn't even check furter from the first character only.

I would appreciate a explanation for this phenomenon. Thank you very much.

Comment: See [`String#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)

Comment: This is just standard lexicographical ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are ordered as in a wordbook.

`string1 > string2` is true if `string1` appears later in the book than `string2`.

"a" is on page 1, "b" is on page 30, so `"a">"b"` is false.

It's the same reason that if you have a folder full of files with numbers in filenames, `10.txt` and `11.txt` appear between `1.txt` and `2.txt`

It's called [lexicographical ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), and it ignores the second letters if the first letters are different.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer was clear and explanatory.